# Mysql STR_TO_TIME formatting

Tags: mysql, sql

My query looks like this:

```
select STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT(MONTH(date), '-', DAY(date) ), '%M-%d' ) from `subscriptions`
```

But the end result is always records with null columns. What is wrong with this formatting?

Expected behaviour:

```
2019-04-20
```

Should become:

```
04-20
```

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A date does per definition contain a year so `STR_TO_DATE` will return `NULL` since it cannot return a date. You can compare `STR_TO_DATE("2020-4-20", '%Y-%m-%d' )` with `STR_TO_DATE("4-20", '%m-%d' )`. The first one is working returning `2020-04-20` while the second one will return `NULL`.

If your goal here is to 0-pad the day and month, have a look at [LPAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

```sql
SELECT CONCAT( LPAD(MONTH(NOW()), 2, 0), "-", LPAD(DAY(NOW()), 2, 0) )
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT( LPAD(MONTH(NOW()), 2, 0), "-", LPAD(DAY(NOW()), 2, 0) ) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 04-29                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**EDIT** I think what you're looking for is in the answer from @nbk; [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%m-%d" )
+------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%m-%d" ) |
+------------------------------+
| 04-29                        |
+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You are making it too complicated.

Your Concat does the trick, but you can use [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

> ```
> SET @a ='2020-04-29';
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CONCAT(LPAD(MONTH(@a),2,0), '-', LPAD(DAY(@a),2,0))
> ```
>
> ```
> | CONCAT(LPAD(MONTH(@a),2,0), '-', LPAD(DAY(@a),2,0)) |
> | :-------------------------------------------------- |
> | 04-29                                               |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@a,'%m-%d')
> ```
>
> ```
> | DATE_FORMAT(@a,'%m-%d') |
> | :---------------------- |
> | 04-29                   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=c381ce1d4208e236b4108695f319c340)*